# Firebase delete Data or refuse reading from real time database after 2 hours BYE FIREBASE ROLES

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my real time database I've time in ms, for example 1619290800000 it's 19:00 gmt and I would like to delete the child where the time is 19:00 gmt on 21:00 gmt by the roles. I've an idea but I don't know how to do it. For example if firebase roles I could do something like this: read: if now - 7200000 > data.child.time.value
Well I'm not good in firebase rules this is not correct I know but just something like this. This won't delete the data but I would not let the user get it, it would also be fine.

[image: Image real time database]

Comment: By "roles" do you mean ["security rules"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)? Are you open to using [scheduled cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)?

Comment: Yeah security rules.. maybe I can reach what I want with the rules... And I don't know anything about the scheduled cloud functions.

Comment: Firebase rules are not filters so this is not a good place to use them. We also don't know your coding platform or what code you've attempted. You can delete a node by calling removeValue or delete a number of nodes by writing nil as their value. Include the code  you tried and what the issue is with that code. Also, please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text so we can use them in answers with copy/paste. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.